# How to clip (crop) image by the spatial location of another image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, clip

I have two raster datasets in geotiff format of different pixel size and extent, although they overlap.  What methods can I use to clip or crop one image based on the spatial location of another image keeping in mind the spatial resolution is different?

[image]

Comment: Good idea @Jigg, post updated to add clarity.

Comment: So you know the position of the upper left corner of the black mask relatively to the origin of the aerial photograph (sorry if I use improper nomenclature) but the pixel sizes are inconsistent, right?

Comment: Correct, the black raster has 1m pixel size and the orange raster has 30m pixel size.  I included the aerial photo just to show that these rasters have a spatial reference.  However, I am only interested in the black and orange rasters.